# Breeze web api controller returns all children, and their children, and their children, and on and on

Tags: breeze

Documentation states that with the web api you do not use the .expand on the breeze query and it will return the navigation properties.  This works great, but how do you prevent it from returning unwanted children.  Seems like I have read somewhere that you can limit the depth that will be returned, but I have not been able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

As long you are NOT lazy loading your navigation properties, then the web api will not send down any navigation properties on your entities. See [Lazy loading discussion here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/efcontextprovider).

The Breeze *EntityQuery.expand* method may then be used to specify exactly which navigation properties you do want to bring down.

Comment: I am using Telerik's OpenAccess ORM and it is using lazy loading.  I thought the BreezeController attribute may have something to do with it.

Comment: I think you need to talk to Telerik and ask them. Sorry!